# How to name my averaging technique?

Tags: average

Suppose, I have a list of values {4, 10, 3, 6, 7, 15, 11}. The average of this number list is avg=8. Now I will select only those elements > avg, which are {10, 11, 15}. Now I am doing average again and selecting the elements bigger than their average. I believe this a helpful technique to get the top rated values from a list, I am not sure about the naming of this averaging technique. Can anybody help me with some name of this method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the Rahman average?

Comment: I think some of its variant is there in practical, but not sure the name, how about using the established term?

Answer (score 2):

How about using Averoveraging?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your code looks like, but I'd imagine on one pass you are returning elements higher than the average? So I would name that method `ElementsGreaterThanAverage`.

If you're only always doing two passes, you could call it `TopQuarterByAveraging` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You're computing the mean, then showing everything over it. Hence OverMean.